# Wildfly spring app filling Eden fast even in idle state

Tags: java, spring, garbage-collection, wildfly

Ours is a Spring based web application deployed on wildfly. We notice the app is filling up Eden space rapidly even when its in idle state.

Few aspects of the application.

It implements few HTTP endpoints. 
It listens to 20 Kafka topics in 200 consumer threads
There are some Quartz scheduler, but they run only once an hour.

[image]

openjdk version "1.8.0_151"

Same behavior is seen even by increasing Eden space to 11GB. I stopped all requests in HTTP and Kafka channel and still notice spikes in Eden space. I'm trying to understand what could cause such memory allocation.

Comment: Did you try profiling? Looking at what threads are doing would help.

Comment: I can monitor the thread states with visualvm, but what are the signs to look for?